# Javascript execute js on a web page such like chrome console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Hi guys i have a question, if i'm on a external web page such as google.com and i want to click on a "whatever" button i open the chrome console and use :

```html
$('input[name="whatever"]').click();
```

and the button get clicked. it works. there is a way to execute the same command on for instance google.com  but not from the console ? like open it in a document like window.open("google.com") and click the button the same way on the web page? thk so much :D

Comment: https://docs.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: `window.open("google.com")`  opens a document from google.com, you can't access that document.

Comment: Assuming there's no URL associated with the action, then not without external logic, no. *Edit* - as @epascarello linked to :)

Comment: @epascarello there aren't others way?

Comment: Same Origin policy prevents you from accessing other webpages from different domains.

Comment: @epascarello do you know which version of selenium i have to download ?

Comment: https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/ does the plugin in the browser and you can record your actions and play it back. Not sure what you want to do exactly, but might be the easiest thing.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not how Javascript is meant to work in the browser. Once the browser starts opening a new document, any code that hasn't been executed yet in the old one stops running and a totally new environment is loaded.

You can experience it firsthand by first running this code in the console and waiting:

```
window.setTimeout(console.log, 5000, 'hi');
```

After 5 seconds, the message 'hi' will display.
Then try this:

```
function test() {
    document.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
    window.setTimeout(console.log, 5000, 'ciao');
}
test();
```

Gooogle will load and no message will be shown in the console.
Basically, your code was aborted and had no access to the new page.

Comment: Thk you for youw answer ! , so there isn't a way to automate click on as webpage o fill a form by i program i made myself ? @roccobarbi

Comment: Not using Javascript in the browser. There are way with other programming languages, though. As an example, Python might be a good choice: it's quite easy to learn and there are books out there that will teach you to do what you asked.